# Is an Android device required to implement RAW_PRIVATE?

Tags: android, android-camera2

Camera2-compatible Android devices can implement the [RAW_PRIVATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#RAW_PRIVATE) image format, which in principle contains unprocessed binary data straight from the image sensor (in contrast with [RAW_SENSOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#RAW_SENSOR), which is almost always processed):

> Private raw camera sensor image format, a single channel image with implementation depedent pixel layout.
>
> RAW_PRIVATE is a format for unprocessed raw image buffers coming from an image sensor. The actual structure of buffers of this format is implementation-dependent.

Although the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd) makes no mention of that parameter, is the presence of this `ImageFormat` at least guaranteed in some way for devices that answer `true` to the [REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_RAW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_RAW) capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not required to be supported.  RAW_SENSOR is the only format guaranteed by [REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_RAW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_RAW).  Any other RAW formats are optional.

RAW_SENSOR should not be processed, by the way - it may be rearranged from the direct-from-sensor 10- or 12-bit MIPI buffer layout, but it should generally otherwise be purely RAW.  (Specifically, it should not be 'linear RAW' or similar).

Even if RAW_PRIVATE is supported, you won't know what its layout is, since it will be device-specific. So using it would require quite a bit of model-specific investigation.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I expected but it's good to have confirmation :)